# How do I create a reusable UserControl and Bind a Command to it?

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, user-controls, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to bind a reusable button in a carusel, what I want to achieve is a add lets say 6 buttons each button will have a command that according to button name will navigate to the proper page.

I can do that by doing this:

```
<toolkitcontrols:Carousel x:Name="NavigationMenuCarouselPanel"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MenuList, Mode=OneWay}"
                                      ItemMargin="25"
                                      ItemDepth="160"
                                      ItemRotationX="180"
                                      ItemRotationY="25"
                                      ItemRotationZ="0"
                                      SelectedIndex="2"
                                      Grid.Row="1">
                <toolkitcontrols:Carousel.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </toolkitcontrols:Carousel.EasingFunction>
                   <Button Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.NavigateToPage1, Mode=OneWay}"
                           Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </toolkitcontrols:Carousel>
```

If I do that, I'll be adding 5 more buttons and i'll have to write properties for each button.

So instead I want to use a UserControl and just write something like this:

```
<toolkitcontrols:Carousel x:Name="NavigationMenuCarouselPanel"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MenuList, Mode=OneWay}"
                                      ItemMargin="25"
                                      ItemDepth="160"
                                      ItemRotationX="180"
                                      ItemRotationY="25"
                                      ItemRotationZ="0"
                                      SelectedIndex="2"
                                      Grid.Row="1">
                <toolkitcontrols:Carousel.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </toolkitcontrols:Carousel.EasingFunction>
                <toolkitcontrols:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ButtonInfo">
                        <usercontrolvm:NavigationMenuButtonTemplate NavigateToPageCommand="{Binding NavigateToPageCommand}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkitcontrols:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
            </toolkitcontrols:Carousel>
```

But I've failed doing it, I found out some tutorial but all as I understand will make me write this like of code:

```
<usercontrolvm:NavigationMenuButtonTemplate NavigateToPageCommand="{Binding NavigateToPageCommand}"/>
```

like 6 times, and i dont know how it will take x:DataType of DataTemplate for my list of properties.

This is my UserControl.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class NavigationMenuButtonTemplate : UserControl
{
    public ButtonInfo ButtonInfo => (DataContext as ButtonInfo);

    public NavigationMenuButtonTemplate()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += NavigationMenuButtonTemplate_Loaded;
    }

    private void NavigationMenuButtonTemplate_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Bindings.Update();
    }

    public DelegateCommand NavigateToPageCommand
    {
        get { return (DelegateCommand)GetValue(NavigateToPageCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NavigateToPageCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for NavigateToPageCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NavigateToPageCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NavigateToPageCommand", 
            typeof(DelegateCommand), 
            typeof(NavigationMenuButtonTemplate), 
            new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

this is my ButtonInfo.cs

```
public class ButtonInfo
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string FontFamily { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public string BenefitKind { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }        
}
```

and this is my UserControl.xaml

```
<Button x:Name="NavigationMenuTemplate"
            Width="300"
            Height="300"
            Command="{Binding NavigateToPageCommand, ElementName=root, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayout">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NavigationMenuIconTextBlock"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       FontFamily="{x:Bind ButtonInfo.FontFamily, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='Webdings'}"
                       Text="{x:Bind ButtonInfo.Symbol, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='&#x91;'}"
                       FontSize="150"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NavigationMenuButtonNameTextBlock"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       Text="{x:Bind ButtonInfo.MenuName, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='CALCULADORA JORNADAS EXTRAORDINARIAS'}"
                       FontSize="12"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NavigationMenuButtonBenefitKindTextBlock"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="{x:Bind ButtonInfo.BenefitKind, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='Subscripción'}"
                       FontSize="10"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NavigationMenuButtonStatusTextBlock"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{x:Bind ButtonInfo.Status, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='Vigente'}"
                       FontSize="10"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>            
    </Button>
```

can somebody help me and point me in the right direction please.
what am I missing?

Comment: All i can understand you don't want to define either buttons or usercontrols 6 times. It would be possible if the usercontrol is a kinda Items Control which can populate UI based on the binding inputs. In your case usercontrol only holds 1 button which will not work.

Comment: When you use UWP, you can use `x:bind` in Click and you can rid of command.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for https://github.com/StuartSmith/UWP-Template10-Carousel-Sample.

Comment: Thanks for that carousel sample, but I kinda like more the experience with the carousel I ve been using right now. but that sample gave me a good idea in how to use it into my app. thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ItemTemplate` approach in your question is actually on the right track.

In the end, your XAML would look something similar to the following(only a few properties are included but you get the idea) -

```
<toolkitcontrols:Carousel ItemsSource="{x:Bind ButtonInfoCollection}">
    <toolkitcontrols:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ButtonInfo">
            <local:NavigationMenuButton NavigateToPageCommand="{Binding DataContext.NavigateToPageCommand, ElementName=MyPageName}" 
                                        NavigateToPageCommandParameter="{x:Bind PageType}" 
                                        MenuName="{x:Bind MenuName}" 
                                        SymbolPath="{x:Bind Symbol}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkitcontrols:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
</toolkitcontrols:Carousel>
```

---

With the structure above in mind, you just need to expose these properties as *dependency properties* in your `NavigationMenuButton` user control. See below as a simple example -

**NavigationMenuButton XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DesignTest.NavigationMenuButton">

    <!--If any of the properties can be updated, change the binding Mode to OneWay-->
    <Button Command="{x:Bind NavigateToPageCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{x:Bind NavigateToPageCommandParameter}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image x:Name="SymbolImage" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MenuName, FallbackValue='JORNADAS EXTRAORDINARIAS', TargetNullValue='JORNADAS EXTRAORDINARIAS'}" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

**NavigationMenuButton Code-behind**

```
public sealed partial class NavigationMenuButton : UserControl
{
    public NavigationMenuButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ICommand NavigateToPageCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(NavigateToPageCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(NavigateToPageCommandProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NavigateToPageCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "NavigateToPageCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(NavigationMenuButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object NavigateToPageCommandParameter
    {
        get => GetValue(NavigateToPageCommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(NavigateToPageCommandParameterProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NavigateToPageCommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "NavigateToPageCommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(NavigationMenuButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string MenuName
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MenuNameProperty);
        set => SetValue(MenuNameProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MenuName", typeof(string), typeof(NavigationMenuButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string SymbolPath
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(SymbolPathProperty);
        set => SetValue(SymbolPathProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SymbolPathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SymbolPath", typeof(string), typeof(NavigationMenuButton), new PropertyMetadata(null, (s, e) =>
        {
            // We don't do the x:Bind for this property in XAML because the Image control's Source property
            // doesn't accept a string but a BitmapImage, so one workaround is to do the conversion here.

            var self = (NavigationMenuButton)s;
            var image = self.SymbolImage;
            var symbolPath = (string)e.NewValue;

           image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(self.BaseUri, symbolPath ?? "/Assets/default_path"));
        }));
}
```

Note you will need to include a `PageType` property in your `ButtonInfo` class for navigation purpose.

```
public Type PageType { get; set; }
```

I personally don't like having a navigation command defined at the item level (i.e in the `ButtonInfo` class), instead, I use an `ElementName` binding in the `Carousel`'s data template to search up a level and bind to the `NavigateToPageCommand` defined in the page's `DataContext`, which is the page's `ViewModel`.

This means that this `ViewModel` will have both `ButtonInfoCollection` and `NavigateToPageCommand` defined like below -

```
public ObservableCollection<ButtonInfo> ButtonInfoCollection { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ButtonInfo>
{
    new ButtonInfo { MenuName = "New Menu", PageType = typeof(BlankPage1), Symbol = "/Assets/StoreLogo.png" }
};

public DelegateCommand<Type> NavigateToPageCommand { get; } = new DelegateCommand<Type>(type => 
    App.Frame.Navigate(type));
```

I hope this all makes sense. Good luck!

Comment: Beautiful answer, I think i liked my answer too, but yours in my opinion has a nice architecture. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Firstable to Dilmah its always posible to build a reusable usercontrol within any itemTemplate. And I'll show you how right now and right here.

I have come up with two solution the first solution its inspire in what I was looking for after reading a lot about databing {x:Bind} and {Binding} markup, I was able to learn how to create a reusable UserControlTemplate

**SOLUTION No.1**

First I'll show you how to create a Navigation menu with a carusel control, which can be found at nuget package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Control

so this is my code now on my MainMenuPage reference to carusel control:

```
<toolkitcontrols:Carousel x:Name="NavigationMenuCarouselPanel"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.NavMenuButtonVMs}"
                                      ItemMargin="25"
                                      ItemDepth="160"
                                      ItemRotationX="180"
                                      ItemRotationY="25"
                                      ItemRotationZ="0"
                                      SelectedIndex="0"
                                      Grid.Row="1">
                <toolkitcontrols:Carousel.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </toolkitcontrols:Carousel.EasingFunction>
                <toolkitcontrols:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <usercontrolvm:NavigationMenuButtonTemplate/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkitcontrols:Carousel.ItemTemplate>                 
            </toolkitcontrols:Carousel>
```

this important part of this code is at ItemSource property which is x:Bind to my NavMenuButtonVms ObservableCollection, and my Usercontrol which is wrapped withing Carousel.ItemTemplate and DataTemplate tags which will allows us to be able to reuse our code and create a N number of controls within our list.

the next is my ViewModel for my MainMenuPage:

```
public class MainMenuPageViewModel : Mvvm.ViewModelBase
{
    ObservableCollection<NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel> _NavMenuButtonVMs = default(ObservableCollection<NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel>);

    public MainMenuPageViewModel()
    {
        Shell.HamburgerMenu.IsFullScreen = false;
        NavMenuButtonVMs = GetNavMenuButtonInfo();
    }

    public string Title => GetLocalizeString("MainMenuPageViewModelTitle");
    public ObservableCollection<NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel> NavMenuButtonVMs
    {
        get { return _NavMenuButtonVMs; }
        private set { Set(ref _NavMenuButtonVMs, value); }
    }

    public override Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        NavigationService.ClearHistory();
        return base.OnNavigatedToAsync(parameter, mode, state);
    }    
}
```

As you can see I initialize my ObservableCollection within my constructor.
The method GetNavMenuButton() is a static class in a Helpers Namespace but i'll show you the code so you can have an idea of how to seed the list also you can notice that I'm not calling the static class that because i'm using C# 6.0 syntax where you can call directly static methods within your class.

you can add a using statement for static classes like this one:

```
using static Ceneam.Helpers.NavigationMenuButtonViewModelHelper;
```

this statement allows you to use a static method like this:

```
GetNavMenuButtonInfo();
```

instead of this:

```
NavigationMenuButtonViewModelHelper.GetNavMenuButtonInfo();
```

I explained this in case you dont understand my code.

then I'll create my usercontrol which I'll show you the xaml, xaml.cs and also the viewmodel.
pay attention to the binding markup at usercontrol since you'll have to quit using x:Bind within a reusable usercontrol.

This is my NavigationMenuButtonTemplate.xaml

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Ceneam.UserControlViews.NavigationMenuButtonTemplate"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Ceneam.UserControlViews"
xmlns:vm="using:Ceneam.ViewModels"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="400"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center">        
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button x:Name="NavigationMenuTemplate"
            Command="{Binding NavigateToPageCommand, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayout">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image x:Name="NavigationMenuIconImage"
                   Source="{Binding ButtonInfo.Symbol, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='ms-appx:///Assets/AssetsMainMenuPage/OverTimeMoneyWhite256x256.png'}"
                   PointerEntered="NavigationMenuIconImage_PointerEntered"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NavigationMenuButtonNameTextBlock"
                       Text="{Binding ButtonInfo.MenuName, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='JORNADAS EXTRAORDINARIAS'}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NavigationMenuButtonBenefitKindTextBlock"
                       Text="{Binding ButtonInfo.BenefitKind, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='Subscripción'}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NavigationMenuButtonStatusTextBlock"
                       Text="{Binding ButtonInfo.Status, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='Vigente'}"/>
        </Grid>            
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

as you can see I'm using binding markup only and the reason is because I use a viewmodel with a parameter that right i had to create a dependency on my usercontrol:

```
public class NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel : Mvvm.ViewModelBase
{
    ButtonInfo _ButtonInfo = default(ButtonInfo);

    public NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel() { }
    public NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel(ButtonInfo buttonInfo)
    {
        ButtonInfo = new ButtonInfo
        {
            BenefitKind = buttonInfo.BenefitKind,
            Status = buttonInfo.Status,
            MenuName = buttonInfo.MenuName,
            Symbol = buttonInfo.Symbol
        };
    }

    public ButtonInfo ButtonInfo
    {
        get { return _ButtonInfo; }
        set { Set(ref _ButtonInfo, value); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand NavigateToPageCommand => new DelegateCommand(async () => { await ExecuteNavigateToPageCommand(); });

    private async Task ExecuteNavigateToPageCommand()
    {
        var message = new MessageDialog("Test");
        await message.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

since you create a contructor with a parameter in the viewmodel I wasnt able to create a strongly type bind with that constructor that is the main reason that made me leave behind x:bind markup for my usercontrol that means that you cant use x:bind methods on events. you will have to use styling methods within the xaml.cs file of your usercontrol.

If you declare in you xaml something like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:usercontrol x:Name=ViewModel/>
<UserControl.DataContext>
```

it will always trigger your parameterless constructor getting rid of your init values of even worse getting NullReferenceExceptions, also you could use DataContext for DesignTime Data but it has to be declare at the beginning of your file and I wont center on it here.

and finally at my static class is where I create my UC (usercontrol) with a parameter in them this is my static class:

```
public static class NavigationMenuButtonViewModelHelper
{
    public static ObservableCollection<NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel> GetNavMenuButtonInfo()
    {
        var data = new ObservableCollection<NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel>();
        AddNavMenuButtonItem(data,
            new NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel(new ButtonInfo
            {
                Symbol = @"ms-appx:///Assets/AssetsMainMenuPage/SatSunBonusWhite256x256.png",
                MenuName = "PRIMAS SABATINAS Y DOMINICALES",
                BenefitKind = "Subscripción",
                Status = "Vigente"
            }));
        AddNavMenuButtonItem(data,
            new NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel(new ButtonInfo
            {
                Symbol = @"ms-appx:///Assets/AssetsMainMenuPage/OverTimeMoneyWhite256x256.png",
                MenuName = "JORNADAS EXTRAORDINARIAS",
                BenefitKind = "Subscripción",
                Status = "Vigente"
            }));
        AddNavMenuButtonItem(data,
            new NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel(new ButtonInfo
            {
                Symbol = @"ms-appx:///Assets/AssetsMainMenuPage/VacationBonusWhite256x256.png",
                MenuName = "PRIMA VACACIONAL",
                BenefitKind = "Gratuito",
                Status = "Vigente"
            }));
        AddNavMenuButtonItem(data,
            new NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel(new ButtonInfo
            {
                Symbol = @"ms-appx:///Assets/AssetsMainMenuPage/PecoWhite256x256.png",
                MenuName = "PERMISOS ECONOMICOS",
                BenefitKind = "Gratuito",
                Status = "Vigente"
            }));
        AddNavMenuButtonItem(data,
            new NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel(new ButtonInfo
            {
                Symbol = @"ms-appx:///Assets/AssetsMainMenuPage/PunctualityBonusWhite256x256.png",
                MenuName = "INCENTIVO PUNTUALIDAD Y ASISTENCIA",
                BenefitKind = "Gratuito",
                Status = "Vigente"
            }));
        AddNavMenuButtonItem(data,
            new NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel(new ButtonInfo
            {
                Symbol = @"ms-appx:///Assets/AssetsMainMenuPage/BonForSeniorityWhite256x256.png",
                MenuName = "BONO DE ANTIGUEDAD",
                BenefitKind = "Gratuito",
                Status = "Vigente"
            }));
        AddNavMenuButtonItem(data,
            new NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel(new ButtonInfo
            {
                Symbol = @"ms-appx:///Assets/AssetsMainMenuPage/WageIncreaseWhite256x256.png",
                MenuName = "RETROACTIVO SUELDO",
                BenefitKind = "Gratuito",
                Status = "Vigente"
            }));

        return data;
    }

    private static void AddNavMenuButtonItem(ObservableCollection<NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel> data, NavigationMenuButtonTemplateViewModel item)
    {
        data.Add(item);
    }
}
```

also if you wish to style properties programatically you should do it at xaml.cs like for example like this one:

```
public sealed partial class NavigationMenuButtonTemplate : UserControl
{
    public NavigationMenuButtonTemplate()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NavigationMenuIconImage_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = (Image)sender;
        var bitmapImage = image.Source as BitmapImage;
        var uri = bitmapImage?.UriSource;
        var uriPath = uri?.AbsolutePath;
        var newUriPath = $@"ms-appx://{uriPath.Replace("White", "Black")}";
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(newUriPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION No.2: **
another solution could be using usercontrols with dependency properties like this one:

```
<toolkitcontrols:Carousel x:Name="NavigationMenuCarouselPanel"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                                      ItemSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MenuList}"
                                      ItemMargin="25"
                                      ItemDepth="160"
                                      ItemRotationX="180"
                                      ItemRotationY="25"
                                      ItemRotationZ="0"
                                      SelectedIndex="0"
                                      Grid.Row="1">
                <toolkitcontrols:Carousel.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </toolkitcontrols:Carousel.EasingFunction>                   
                <usercontrolvm:NavigationMenuButtonTemplate ButtonInfo="{x:Bind ViewModel.MenuList[0],Mode=OneWay}"
```

NavigateToPageCommand = "{x:Bind ViewModel.NavigateToPageCommand}"/>

You will have to create a NavigationMenuButtonTemplate.xaml.cs with dependency properties like this one:

```
public sealed partial class NavigationMenuButtonTemplate : UserControl
{
    public NavigationMenuButtonTemplate()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DelegateCommand NavigateToPageCommand
    {
        get { return (DelegateCommand)GetValue(NavigateToPageCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NavigateToPageCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for NavigateToPageCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NavigateToPageCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NavigateToPageCommand", 
            typeof(DelegateCommand), 
            typeof(NavigationMenuButtonTemplate), 
            new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public ButtonInfo ButtonInfo
    {
        get { return (ButtonInfo)GetValue(ButtonInfoProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonInfoProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ButtonInfo.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonInfoProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonInfo", 
            typeof(ButtonInfo), 
            typeof(NavigationMenuButtonTemplate), 
            new PropertyMetadata(0));        
}
```

I dont like this solution because I'll have to repeat code at xaml file but its a good choice too.

Hope you like my answer I think it can be used by many of us and its appliable to many other controls with your endless imagination.

Comment: I would just create a usercontrol that wraps a button and exposes dependency properties like Symbol, ToPageType, etc.

Comment: My usercontrol wraps a button, but it doesnt expose dependency properties. could you share a sample of you solution I would appreciate to learn and understand your idea. grettings buddy!!!

Comment: Sure, I just posted an answer. :)